# How to Moderate Edits to User Profiles?

Tags: users, user-roles, user-meta, moderation, workflow

I would like to moderate WordPress users’ edits to their own profiles. As I understand it, the default would be for the profile changes to go online immediately. Instead, I’d like to leave the older version online, until an Admin has approved the edit.

I've checked several of the moderation plugins (e.g. Revisionary), and the user directory plugins, but they only seem to moderate the *creation* of users, not their *revision*.

How could the revisions be moderated?

Comment: It depends on your approach. If user profile's are posts, then you'd simply need a way to have all edits need approval (plenty of resources for this). However for a WP-profile this would be trickier.

Comment: I'm asking specifically about the WP-profiles, not posts.